# How to change css class generated by javascript

Tags: jquery, angularjs, vis.js

i'm using visjs library, it works good, but i cant change css class generated by this libary(vis js) because the divs are generated by the javascript of the library.
how i can change the class of these divs please!! 
i tried to use this but it didnt worked:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {                
   $(".vis-item").css("background-color", "red");
 });
 $( document ).ready(function() {                
   $(".vis-item").css("background-color", "red");
 });
```

Comment: Do you want to change css class or style tag of your DIvs?

Comment: Can you pls share the code..

Comment: css of a div but this div is generated by javascript

Comment: the code of visjs library is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addClass` to over right existing class rather then inline css .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {                
   $(".vis-item").addClass('red');
 });
```

CSS:

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt worked..the class of the divs are generated by javascript..you realize the problem

Comment: After render your html you can addClass. To ensure that you can debug  for `.vis-item`.length.

Answer (score 1):

To add css class to some element:

```
 $('yourSelector').addClass('className');
```

To remove css class from some element:

```
 $('yourSelector').removeClass('className');
```

To change inline css that is style attribute of your html tag:

```
 $('yourSelector').css('display', 'block');
 $('yourSelector').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

And so on..This way you can add css properties in style attribute of your html tag. You can remove by passing empty string from style attribute like:

```
 $('yourSelector').css('width', '');    //This will removwe width property
```

Comment: thanks ..i know all that but it didnt impact in the element i dont know why..but when i create a function and i put inside the selector above and when i click the button it works..do you realize the problem??

Comment: Make sure, your divs are rendered before manipulating them in jquery.